# Detecting a DLL version number using a script

Tags: dll, scripting, vbscript, versions

I would like to write a script that can recursively scan the DLLs in a directory and generate a report of all of their version numbers.

How can I detect the version number of a DLL using a script? VBScript solutions are preferred, unless there is a better way.

Comment: If you want to do it in VB6. Check this out. Worked 100% for me:
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4976&lngWId=1

Comment: You might look at PowerShell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50.aspx) object to access the file system and its [`GetFileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4e05k97.aspx) method to obtain the file version information.

You asked for a VBScript example, so here you are:

```
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PrintDLLVersions oFSO.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))

Sub PrintDLLVersions(Folder)
  Dim oFile, oSubFolder

  ' Scan the DLLs in the Folder
  For Each oFile In Folder.Files
    If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "DLL" Then
      WScript.Echo oFile.Path & vbTab & oFSO.GetFileVersion(oFile)
    End If
  Next

  ' Scan the Folder's subfolders
  For Each oSubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    PrintDLLVersions oSubFolder
  Next
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
> cscript //nologo script-file.vbs folder > out-file
```

e.g.:

```
> cscript //nologo dll-list.vbs C:\Dir > dll-list.txt
```

Sample output:

```
C:\Dir\foo.dll 1.0.0.1
C:\Dir\bar.dll  1.1.0.0
C:\Dir\SubDir\foobar.dll    4.2.0.0
...
```

Comment: Solution is very helpfull but i want make call cscript //nologo dll-list.vbs C:\Dir > dll-list.txt in bath file for my pepole from test team. Itried Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run("cscript //nologo dll-list.vbs C:\Dir > dll-list.txt") but version of files are on screen instead in dll-list.txt file

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I think [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.general/2006-03/msg00518.html) is the source I referenced

This is the script that I use, I apologize, but I don't recall from where. (So,reader, if this started as your script please step forward) It uses the FileSystemObject which can get version directly.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set vbs="%temp%\filever.vbs"
set file=%1

echo Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") >%vbs%
echo WScript.Echo oFSO.GetFileVersion(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)) >>%vbs%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
'cscript.exe //Nologo %vbs% %file%') do set filever=%%a

del %vbs%
echo Full file version of %file% is: %filever%

for /f "tokens=2 delims=. " %%a in ("%filever%") do set secondparam=%%a
set splevel=%secondparam:~0,1%
echo SP level is: %splevel%

endlocal
pause
```